# How to emulate keyboard input under Wayland in C++?

Tags: c++, virtual-keyboard, wayland

I'm trying to send a keyboard input from a C++ application (I'm using Qt5 framework). I successfully run ydotool as external QProcess but I'm searching for a better and more "c++" way of doing this, without using external modules (ydotool needs a runtime run as root and each command must be run as root too, it needs some work to make it work correctly, I'd like something simpler from the user side).
Any idea?

thanks in advance!